# Use property value in annotation?

Tags: java

I have this annotated class in one of my projects.
The annotation class is defined by me.

Question: can I instead of the String `"TP_REPORT"` use some property
whose value is not known at compile time but only at runtime?

```java
@PhoenixTable(tableName="TP_REPORT")
public class TPData {
    ...
}
```

Just as a reference, here is the definition of my annotation type.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface PhoenixTable {

    public String tableName();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not possible in `Java`. Values in an annotation should be constant at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to some official reference which says this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give any object reference since you don't have any object when declaring an annotation. From docs by Oracle ([click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html)):

> Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums,
>   annotations, and arrays of the preceding types.

But if you absolutely need something dynamic, you can give a class and use that class to read from some property file. Although this may not be the best solution for you, it may give you something to investigate.

```
public interface TableNameProp{
    public static String getTableName(){
        return "TP_REPORT"; //or read from some prop and use it
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface PhoenixTable {

    public Class<TableNameProp> tableProps();

}

@PhoenixTable(tableProps=TableNameProp.class)
public class TPData {
    ...
}
```